# Trying to make DataSet read from Xml file to add values to ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I am kinda newbie on Visual basic 2010, and wanted to create a chat loader, and i wanted it to read values from a xml table.

This is the code i have used in Vb.

```
 ChatXml.ReadXmlSchema(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/../Release/chat.xml")
 ChatXml.ReadXml(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/../Release/chat.xml")
 ComboBox1.DataSource = ChatXml.Tables
 ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "chat"
```

And the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <chat>
    <gn>Help</gn>
    <gid>1913106</gid>
    <xc>2336</xc>
    <cn>1500337760</cn>
    <g8>g8</g8>
 </chat>
```

That i want it to do, is to read the value "gn", and add it to the ComboBox, i am not sure what is wrong, tried the "Google is your friend" and could not find something that worked.

The error i get is this.

```
Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.
enter code here
```

Not sure, but tried to add data to the Tables in DataSet, but seems i can't get it to work.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are instructing the combo box to show all the rows in the chat table, rather than telling it to show all the `gn` fields in the chat table.  You need to do this:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = ChatXml.Tables(0)
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "gn"
```